# How to find the orthogonal projection onto Im(A)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have the following matrix, which should represent a linear transformation:

$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Now, I want to find the orthogonal projection $p: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ onto Im($A$).

What I have done so far is to find the orthonormal matrix of $A$, which is:

$\begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{6} \\ -\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{6} 
\\ 0 & \dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{3}  \end{pmatrix} \\$

By using the Gram-Schmidt process for finding the orthonormal vectors. Am I on the right path? I have no idea what I should do honestly.

Comment: What do you mean by the "orthonormal matrix of $A$"?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. It remains to calculate the projection matrix $P=BB^T$.

Comment: @Hasek the matrix after I do Gram-Schmidt process with the columns of A